# WPF datagrid custom column

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a solution to bind from a dataset a collumn and convert the database DateTime value to Date value and display it?
Also i would like a boolean column from the database to be displayed as True/ False and not checkbox...Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps add a wpf tag so that all the wpf gurus will know to look at this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [converters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to control the way the bound data is displayed

For instance, to display true/false:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(string))]
public class TrueFalseConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool boolean = (bool)boolean;
        return boolean.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
// Convert the other way around if needed else throw NotImplementedException...
    }
}
```

Comment: tried that works great:)But for date stringformat did the trick.. however for other collumn i used that